# Conditional independence expansion

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have four random variables **A,B,C** and **S**. A,B and C are conditionally independent given S. So, I need to obtain **P(A,B,C,S)**

By the chain rule:
$$P(A,B,C,S)=P(S)P(A|S)P(B|A,S)P(C|A,B,S)$$
By the conditional independence
$$P(B|A,S)=P(B|S)$$
Is this correct? $$P(C|A,B,S)=P(C|S)$$
So $$P(A,B,C,S)=P(S)P(A|S)P(B|S)P(C|S)$$

Also I have doubts in the calculation of the joint probability between A,B and C.
$$P(A,B,C)=P(A)P(B|A)P(C|A,B)$$
I am not sure how to compute $P(C|A,B)$ I know the diverse marginal probabilities and conditional between two variables.
Thanks.

Comment: That A,B and C are conditionally independent given S means exactly that P(A,B,C|S)=P(A|S)P(B|S)P(C|S).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Did commented, $A$, $B$, and $C$ being conditionally independent given $S$ immediately gives $P(A,B,C \mid S) = P(A \mid S) P(B \mid S) P(C \mid S)$. Your final answer is correct, but you made some unnecessary steps.

To find $P(A,B,C)$, sum over all possible instances of $S$.
$$P(A,B,C)=\sum_{s} P(A,B,C,S=s).$$